# Laravel: How to get the latest record in group of records with where condition?

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have two tables which are named as `students` and `cities`. `students` table has a primary key which is related to the `cities` table.

Students table:
[image: Students table]

In the frontend, I would like to have the data of the `cities` table with these requirements:

1. The data of the `students` table must be grouped by `city_id`
2. If there are more than one records with the same `city_id` in the `students` table, select only the latest record of the group.
3. Search in the latest records and select only students who are inactive.

Here is the relationship function of the `city` model:

```
public function student()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Student::class, 'city_id', 'id')->orderByDesc('id');
}
```

This is my controller function:

```
$data = City::whereHas('student', function($query){
              $query->where('is_active', 0)
        })->with('student')->get();
```

**Expected result:** Considering the sample data, the query must return nothing.

**Current result:** It returns the third row as there is an inactive student record in the second row. So in this case `where` condition doesn't work properly.

I can get expected result with this SQL query:

```
select *
  from students s
 where id = (select max(t2.id)
               from students s2
              where s.city_id = s2.city_id) AND is_active = '0';
```

How can I fix this logical error?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
public function inactiveStudent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Student::class, 'city_id', 'id')
                ->where('is_active', 0)
                ->orderByDesc('id');
}
```

```
$data = City::whereHas('inactive_student')
            ->with('inactive_student')
            ->get();
```

I'm not certain if it's `inactive_student` or `inactiveStudent` when you do the query.

Comment: Oops, sorry I have just edited the SQL query @cbaconnier

Comment: No problem, I saw something was wrong, so I assumed my answer based on your code and your explanation

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately, it still returns the second row. I really don't know why @cbaconnier

Comment: I think you will need a subquery then. Are you using laravel 5.* or laravel 6?

Comment: I'm using 5.8 @cbaconnier

Comment: I don't think I will have the time to test and confirm you (because I'm really not sure) But **think** subquery will help you. Unfortunally they came natively only since Laravel 6. However the author (reinink) did an article to use them with laravel 5.8 https://reinink.ca/articles/dynamic-relationships-in-laravel-using-subqueries also a talk about it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBUXXErAtuk